# Want to know what is the number in output?

Tags: python

What are the numbers "0x056D44F0" depicting for is it a memory location or a error plz tell?

The code is:-

```
def myfunc(a):
  return len(a)

x = map(myfunc, ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry'))

print(x)
```

I am eager to what that what is the number depicting in the output?

Comment: It's not an error at all, it's a printed representation of a map object. Try `print(list(x))` to print the list.

Comment: "I was expecting the length of the list in x to be printed" Why? Your code _explicitly_ shows that `x` is a map, not a list.

Comment: You can iterate over `x` as though it were a list, but it's not a list.

Comment: Related: [Getting a map() to return a list in Python 3.x](/q/1303347/4518341), [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](/q/13638898/4518341),  [**Why** does map return a map object instead of a list in Python 3?](/q/40015439/4518341) If you're learning from Python 2 materials, you should know that Python 2 hit EOL 2020-01-01, and Python 3 is way better anyway.

Comment: Yes that is the memory location. That's documented under [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr): *"... a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object"*

Comment: Please keep in mind that Python 2.7 has been **unmaintained, even for essential security fixes, since Jan 1, 2020**. It is approximately as old as Windows 7. If Python 2.7 came with your computer then **do not attempt to remove it, as this can seriously damage your operating system**; but please try to write code for an up-to-date Python version, make sure you have one installed, and make sure you can enforce that the code runs with that version instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. `map` is a class, and that's the default representation of the class. It can't actually show the elements that were mapped to, because `map` is an iterator, and that would exhaust the iterator.

You can get the mapped values by "forcing" the iterator:

```
print(list(x))
```

`list` consumes the iterator and creates a list from it.

It's also idiomatic to use a list comprehension unless you need a lazy object. That way you don't need to create an iterator, then create a list from the iterator:

```
x = [myfunc(elem) for elem in ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry')]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Can u plz tell what is that weird number in the output? is it the memory location or what?

Comment: @SameerTaniyalam Yes. It's the unique identity of the object, which, in CPython, is the memory address of the object.